# execute multiple statements in one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i need your help. I'm implementing a small ecommerce site and im executing two queries to get the result as follows:

My database table 'cart'

```
id  itemid  qty   price   customerid
1    item1   1    2500        1 
2    item2   1    11000       1
```

I need to get 'item1' price, so i'm using following query

```
SELECT qty, price FROM cart WHERE itemid='item1';
```

I also need to get sum of all items prices based on customerid so i'm using following one.

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS totalprice, COUNT(*) AS totalitems FROM cart WHERE customerid='1';
```

How to get the two results by executing query at once using mysql_query() in php mysql;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from the official documentation "mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)"

Comment: Is your current code working for your purpose? May be if you explain why do you need this in the same call we can help out in some way with your inquiry.

Comment: I think executing multiple queries will consume bandwidth and cause provide response slowly! Is there any procedure two get the sum of all the prices of a particular customerid and price of a particular item in single execution ?

Comment: @Alariva yes those two queries are working fine and i'm getting result as i needed but i want to reduce the queries execution to save the time and bandwidth.

Comment: Then you should indicate the purpose of your question as optimization, and, that is not affecting the time of your queries. You should face your problem by showing the tables definition, indexes, amount of rows and the execution time to analyze the posibilty of optimizing them.

Comment: Yes i'm considering both solutions but settled with your's for NOW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only building a small site, there is an ugly workaround you can use; implement a sub-query that includes the sum in each row; like this:

```
SELECT
    qty, price,
    (SELECT SUM(price) FROM cart WHERE customerid='1') as totalprice,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart WHERE customerid='1') AS totalitems
FROM
    cart
WHERE
    itemid='item1';
```

Comment: Thanks @Sjon for the response, let me check this and confirm.

Comment: You're welcome. I have to say though, the solution posted by @Ollie Jones is definitely prettier

Answer (score 1):

You could eliminate one of the two roundtrips from php to MySQL by using a `UNION ALL` operation and getting your data in a couple of rows.

```
SELECT 'item' name, itemid item, qty, price FROM cart WHERE itemid='item1'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'count',      customerid, COUNT(*), 0  FROM cart WHERE customerid='1'
```

Or you could summarize your cart with [an aggregate `WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

```
SELECT customerid, item, SUM(qty) qty, SUM(price) price, COUNT(*) items
  FROM cart
 GROUP BY customerid, item WITH ROLLUP 
 WHERE customerid ='1'
```

This will give back a result set that ends with a summary line for the customerid.  It may be what you want.

It has to be said: eliminating just one extra php <--> MySQL round trip probably is not worth your development effort.